# Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit - lt's stuck on the splash screen when booted from USB in the "Try Ubuntu" option

Tags: ubuntu

I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr), 32 bit, and I put it in a USB flash drive of 4 GB using linuxusb software.

When I booted it from USB, a menu appeared, having options like:

- *Try Ubuntu*
- *Install ubuntu*
- *Memtest*
- *Advanced options*
- etc.

I have Windows 7 Ultimate on my PC, and I don't want to install Ubuntu.
I just wanted to try it.

When I clicked on it, it went to the splash screen and remained there only.
Even if I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> it shows a blank black screen and when I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> again it shows the splash screen. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to get rid of this splash screen but a work-around could be the use of a VM Player. There you can test it as you want.

Comment: Is vm good performance wise since my pc is quite old .2gb ram dual core 2.6 ghz processor

Comment: well you decide how many resources you want to let the vm use but yeah the less resources it has the lower the performance will be.